# Best Way to include javascript in java servlets

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

i actually read a tutorial about servlets and i saw two different ways to include javascript in servlets.

```
  out.println("<html><head>");

  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(
      "/WEB-INF/javascript/functions.js");

  dispatcher.include(request, response);

  out.println("<title>Client Forms</title></head><body>");
```

and the other possiblity:

```
out.println("<html><head>");
out.println("<script language="text/javascript" src="functions.js">");
...
```

what is the difference between using an dispatcher or including directly? what is the better solution?

thx for your advices..

Comment: Best Way is use JSP's instead of servlets !

Comment: Servlet = html in java code , JSP = java in HTML , for quick reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we use the `RequestDispatcher`, we are actually making request from the server for the said JS file and then we embed it into the response document.

On the other hand, embedding a  tag will point the browser to make such a request to the server. I guess both the approaches are going to fetch the same results 99% of time at least if your file is on different server.

On the other hand, if it is on the same server, I think RequestDispatcher will be faster.

Server side caching will help in first approach and client side one in other.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script language="text/javascript" src="functions.js">
```

In this case browser could cache script and it won't load on next page load if it's content [haven't changed](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5). Caching resources saves time on page load and network traffic. It doesn't matter whether you use this snippet in servlet or jsp.

By the way, there is a bug in your first way of including script. *.js files usually contain only javascript code, whithout markup, so you should add opening script tag before and closing script tag after including content of functions.js:

```
out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/javascript/functions.js");
out.println("</script>");
```